# multiplatform library from single chip C project

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, windows, xamarin

I am trying to use code from single chip processor project, compiled in (Eclipse) Code Composer Studio Version: 6.1. (Texas Instruments). It is easy, but relatively large code. There are several buttons, led diodes and alphanumeric display.
I need to take logic of this single chip project and implement it on multiplatform library used with C# - Xamarin, which I can use in Windows, Android, Ios Mac and Ipad.

Which is the best way to do multiplatform library?

for example,

```
int p;
extern int __multp(int a, int b)
{   p=p+a*b;
    return p+(a*b);
}
```

If I compile it with Eclipse CDT and MinGW, compiler makes 22KB large library which needs libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (112KB). This library works on C# Windows, but not in Android and Ios platform.

Is any way how to do one library for all platforms? Using in C# .net Xamarin.
Thanks a lot,
David.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, *one library for all platforms* is the same code base that may be compiled by different compilers, generating different binaries for different target platforms. Usually people try to put everything in one directory tree. Different compilers may start from different directories or from the same directory, but it must be clear what belongs to what platform. Usually there are subdirectories with target-specific stuff.

Note that it is not unusual to see that someone has fixed a bug on Windows and broke the Android build.

If you do not compile and test for some target, consider it broken or dead.
You cannot develop 2 months for one target and 2 months for another.